# Adding a taxonomy tag to wordpress post by writing it in comment with hashtag

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, taxonomy

In wordpress, I have a post with some tags. A user should be able to add a tag to the post by writing the tag with a hashtag in the comment, e.g. 'This is a comment that adds #orange' should add the tag orange.

That is my code:

```
function add_tag_from_comment( $comment_ID ) {
    $comment = get_comment($comment_ID);
    $search_text = strip_tags( str_replace( array( "\n", "\r"), $comment->comment_content));
    preg_match_all('/#([\d\w-_]+)[\b|]{0,3}/', $search_text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        wp_set_post_tags( $comment->comment_post_ID, $match, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'add_tag_from_comment', 10, 2 );
```

If I replace `$comment->comment_content` with a text like 'This is a comment that adds #oranges', then it works. But it does not work when I write the actual comment and I don't know the reason. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Check the contents of $comment ( `echo $comment` ) it may be the case that the data is somehow slashed or encoded in a way that the regex is unable to catch the hashtag in the content.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, I can't access the log files or the console. Is there another way to debug and show the comment content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on [Sco's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197050/5317828):

```
add_action('comment_post', 'tag_comment_insert', 2);
function tag_comment_insert($comment) {
    $comment_text = get_comment_text($comment);
    $current_comment = get_comment( $comment );
    $comment_post_id = $current_comment->comment_post_ID;
    preg_match_all('/#([\d\w-_]+)[\b|]{0,3}/', $comment_text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    wp_set_post_tags( $comment_post_id, $matches[1], true );
}

add_action('comment_text', 'tag_comment', 2);
function tag_comment($comment) {
    $comment = preg_replace('/#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/i', '<a class="hashtag" href="'.get_home_url().'/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $comment);
    return $comment;
}
```

The problem before was that the `post_ID` was not set. My solution seems to be a bit complicated, so any shortening is appreciated. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_action('comment_post', 'tag_comment_insert', 2);
    function tag_comment_insert($comment) {
      $comment_text = get_comment_text($comment);
      preg_match_all('/#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', $comment_text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
      wp_set_post_tags( $comment, $matches[1], true );
    }

    add_action('comment_text', 'tag_comment', 2);
    function tag_comment($comment) {
      $comment = preg_replace('/#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/i', '<a class="hashtag" href="'.get_home_url().'/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $comment);
      return $comment;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The second function works, but the first one does not in my case. The tag is added to the general tag list, but not linked to the post. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: I narrowed down the problem. If I use the id of the post e.g. `wp_set_post_tags(12, $matches[1], true);`, then the tag is added to the post. Using `$comment` or `$comment->comment_post_ID`don't work.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
$comment = get_comment($comment_ID);
```

with

```
$comment = get_comments($comment_ID);
```