# Add A WordPress Taxonomy Tag for Hashtags in WordPress Content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tags, posts

WordPress taxonomies help in SEO, and they make sites with a large number of posts easy to sort. How can we convert any word starting with ' #' as a WordPress Tag automatically, whenever a post saves.

My site has 100s of posts, and authors Don't like to put tags. Using the system of hashtags can ensure that they enjoy putting tags.

For every WordPress post save, I want to find Words starting with ' #' for example 'An #Apple A Day' and convert #Apple to the default WordPress tag. Also, I want to do it for all post types.

I found a good explanation of how to do in comments, but because I'm not good at PHP, I couldn't do it with WordPress post's content.

[Adding a taxonomy tag to wordpress post by writing it in comment with hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196223/adding-a-taxonomy-tag-to-wordpress-post-by-writing-it-in-comment-with-hashtag/47197050#47197050)

I tried to do it with wp_insert_post_data, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must to build an plugin for wordpress that hook into the published post or an update post you can refer into [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)
after that you can add tag whenever they find hastag on post_content and the code goes like this

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $content = $post->post_content;
    preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){
            wp_set_post_tags( $ID, trim($matchKey), true);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

if you use frontier post maybe you can use this

```
function post_published_from_frontier($my_post){
    $content = $my_post->post_content;
    $ID = $my_post->ID;
    preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){
            wp_set_post_tags( $ID, trim($matchKey), true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('frontier_post_post_save', post_published_from_frontier, 10 ,2 );
```

you can change the parameter of add_action priority refer to [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
and to change all of the hastag in the post into url you can use the code like this

```
function old_wp_content( $content ) { 
    $content =  preg_replace('/ #([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/', ' <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://milyin.com/hashtag/$1\">$1</a>', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'old_wp_content' );
```

so if we combine all of the code into one plugin we can use it like this

```
<?php
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $content = $post->post_content;
    preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){
            wp_set_post_tags( $ID, trim($matchKey), true);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );

function post_published_from_frontier($my_post){
    $content = $my_post->post_content;
    $ID = $my_post->ID;
    preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){
            wp_set_post_tags( $ID, trim($matchKey), true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('frontier_post_post_save', post_published_from_frontier, 10 ,2 );

function old_wp_content( $content ) { 
    $content =  preg_replace('/ #([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/', ' <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://milyin.com/hashtag/$1\">$1</a>', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'old_wp_content' );
```

Comment: Hi there, first of all shouldn't we use save_post rather than publish_post action, because authors can have private posts also... Secondly, i want to insure that there must be a space ' ' before hashtag. For eg. If content is 'An#Apple' then it should not convert #Apple to the wordpress tags and leave it blank... Also, can can i automatically create links for hashtags to the respective taxonomy pages...

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal the truth is save_post and publish_post is same in the function. the different is publish_post run first. and for the case of space i already edit my answer

Comment: Well Sir, I am sorry to tell, the code didn't work. I in order to prevent conflicts disabled all other plugins, but still i can confirm tags are not created. The debug.log says "invalid argument provided for foreach()"

Comment: hi @AdityaAgarwal i already edit my code, sorry my bad  because  i don't check the regex patter from the url you gave in the post. you can try my code again it can detect the hashtag in content

Comment: Hey once again, I am thankful for your help and it works perfectly. Can u please do a small favor of helping me do the string replace so that every hashtag converts into a link... For example #Apple could link to https://milyin.com/hashtag/Apple ...

Comment: Hey there, Your code is running fine, but i have frontend form using a plugin frontier post, which users can use to add or edit posts... Editing post throught it doesn't add tags. I tried the actions and hooks they provided but couldn't work... Is there anyway to run the function any time the post changes?

Comment: hay @AdityaAgarwal i already edit my answer you can check for the answer and also you can upvote my answer for other people who seek the same question with you

Comment: An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 23 of the file Error message: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

Comment: hi sorry i forgot the $_POST attribute are you using this plugin https://github.com/wp-plugins/frontier-post ?

Comment: Yes sir... That's the plugin... Well you seem to know the actions of that plugin pretty well.. suprised... But ya the plugin is that only

Comment: hai @AdityaAgarwal can you check the code,  i already add a new code to change all of you hashtag into url you can change the url in old_wp_content function. and also i already add the hook for frontier post. i know the actions on that plugin based on this https://github.com/wp-plugins/frontier-post/blob/ffeb8cb1cf1c965e34ea92136e867b58492b1942/frontier-submit-form.php#L255 you can take a look in their plugin repository. And also if this already answer your problem don't forget to click accepted and voted my answer thanks

Comment: Thanks for help... U have solved all my problems.. You are amazing... Rarely do we find people like you who solve issues highly specific to us, and help us integrate with our plugins... Thank You for everything...

Comment: Hey, One last help needed, I want the actual tags also to have the hashtag.... Currently #Apple convert to Apple in WordPress tags... I tried removing the strip(), that didn't work... I did '#'.$matchKey that didn't work... Can u please help 

Comment: so you want the tag to become #apple or only apple?

Comment: #apple it needs to be

Comment: i think you have another plugin or restriction in you database that remove '#'. because the logic will save '#' in your tag. and also you can ask another question in stackoverflow for this problem if you want. because it's already out of the topic

Comment: Hi @dennisgon how to add the tag without the # symbol finally?